# Redirect URL on Sign In link from the Navbar

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, razor-pages

I've been building a razor pages ASP.Net Core 3.1 website, and there are some pages that have content that is visible without authentication, and when the user is authenticated, it shows additional information.

When a user visits a page that requires full authorisation it immediately takes them to the AzureAD login page, logs them in and then redirects them to the page that they were just on.

When the Sign In link is clicked on the header on a page where authorisation is required to view additional details, it takes them to the AzureAD login page, logs them in, then redirects them to the **index page**. I would like this link to have the same behavior and redirect them to the page they were just on.

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
<ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="navbar-text nav-item">Hello @User.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value!</li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a></li>
</ul>
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn" >Sign in</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

**Example**

If the user gets the link via a QR code for example, it won't sign the user in automatically. When they click the sign in link, it redirects the user to the index page. The user then needs to go back to the QR code app and either rescan the code or reclick on the link to get back to the same page.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks Nan Yu for the below solution. I've modified it to accept the query string.

**_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" asp-area="" asp-route-path="@Context.Request.Path" asp-route-query="@Context.Request.QueryString" asp-page="/Account" asp-page-handler="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

**Account.cshtml**

```
  public IActionResult OnGetSignIn(string path, string query)
        {

            var redirectUrl = Url.Content("~/");

            if(Url.IsLocalUrl(path+query))
                return Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = path + query },
                    AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return Redirect("~/");


        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the logic to achieve that in Razor page application :

1. Add Account razor page in Pages folder , and add a method to triage the authentication challenge with current page's path :

   ```
   public IActionResult OnGetSignIn(string path)
   {

       var redirectUrl = Url.Content("~/");
       return Challenge(
           new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = path },
           AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
   }
   ```

In _LoginPartial , modify the route and set the path like :

```
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark"  asp-area="" asp-route-path="@Context.Request.Path" asp-page="/Account" asp-page-handler="SignIn" >Sign in</a>
    </li>
```

After user is authenticated , user will be redirect to RedirectUri confige in AuthenticationProperties .

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

I had to modify it slightly to accept the QueryString but it works! Is there any chance in this method of a Redirect Attack? I've surrounded it, so it checks, but I want to know if it's useless.